# How to avoid the CORS error from an API created in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a React Application to upload a file to the S3 bucket. To do this, I have created a PUT API from the AWS API Gateway and the API is working well in the POSTMAN. **The problem is, when I call the API from my React Application locally (http://localhost:3000), I'm getting a CORS error from the PUT request and a 403 error from the OPTIONS request (Preflight)**. How can I solve this?

**Here is the bucket policy**

[image]

**Here is the Bucket CORS Policy**

[image]

**Here are the Enable CORS settings of the API in the API Gateway**

[image]

**The Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bucket policy does not allow `putObject` method. CORS can be seen when some unrelated errors happen. I encourage you to enable INFO logging for API Gateway and check what exactly happens. Share the logs and it will be easier to tell.

To enable INFO logging for API Gateway, go to API -> Settings -> add CloudWatch log role ARN which would have permission to write into cloudwatch logs. Then enable full INFO logs. You will find logs inside CloudWatch logs

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is the log I get

`{
    "requestId": "2d460029-7e83-466a-84ba-0c07be38c39f",
    "ip": "103.227.245.59",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "16/Mar/2022:10:25:28 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "resourcePath": "/v1/ppppp/sssss.jpg",
    "status": "403",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  }`

Comment: on each single request there should be like 20-30 lines of logs on everything what happens on API Gateway and then integration. Including all mapping and everything. Your sample log is very limited.

Comment: I hope this will be enough 

`{
    "requestId": "d3ca6f4f-68cd-4976-8afc-476a07550d62",
    "ip": "103.227.245.59",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "16/Mar/2022:10:38:23 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "resourcePath": "/v1/psrtempbucket/sudaraka.jpg",
    "status": "403",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "42",
    "error": "Missing Authentication Token",
    "authoriseError": "-",
    "authoriserError": "-",
    "authenticateError": "-"
}`

Comment: this is basic request log of body/headers and not full logs that do include everything what happens inside API Gateway & it's integration & mapping before/after calling integration. Those full logs won't fit here in comment for sure. As said, it should be like 20-30 lines of debug data.

Comment: Now I have the full error log. In a certain step, the log has this statement `Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request` for the OPTIONS method

Comment: check this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-template-invoke-error/